# How to use PodTemplate

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I saw that there is an object named `PodTemplate` which have little [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#pod-templates).

It is mentioned:

> Pod templates are pod specifications which are included in other
>   objects, such as **Replication Controllers**, **Jobs**, and **DaemonSets**.

But I am not sure how to mention it on `Replication Controllers`, `Jobs` or `DaemonSets`.

I created a `PodTemplate` like this:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: PodTemplate
metadata:
  name: pod-test
  namespace: default
template:
  metadata:
    name: pod-template
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: container
      image: alpine
      command: ["/bin/sh"]
      args: ["-c", "sleep 100"]
EOF
```

I want to use it in a `DaemonSet`, how can I do it ?

Here is an example for `DaemonSet` YAML:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: pod-by-daemonset
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: selector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: selector
    spec:
      containers: # I don't want to specify it, I want to use the template.
      - name: container
        image: alpine 

EOF
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interestingly the [page for DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) gives an example of creating a DaemonSet and says that

> the .spec.template is a pod template. It has exactly the same schema
>   as a Pod, except it is nested and does not have an apiVersion or kind.

So the intention is to inline the Pod schema in the DaemonSet.

However, there does [seem to have been a plan](http://docker.codescode.com/about-podtamplate/) to be able to reference a PodTemplate by the form:

```
TemplateRef:
Name: <templatename>
```

What [seems to have happened from the trail on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8109) is that this way of referencing a predefined PodTemplate was added but not finished and then removed. You can give it a try but it looks to me like only the inline spec is supported.